# Isolators and Level shifters - default to logic 1

Tags: digital-logic, digital-communications, level-shifting, digital-modulation, level-translation

I've been making my first boards to do some testing in power electronics. I'm testing unpowered circuits, and there's something that baffles me.

I'm testing if pulses appear correctly on gate drives etc, while feeding the pulses from a function generator. So far, when I feed an input to these devices, they seem to work as expected. The moment I press output OFF on the signal generator however, they default to 5V (on). Do you know why this is caused and what I could do to remedy this situation?

The components I'm using is TI's ISO7820, and one of TI's level shifters.

Comment: Circuit diagrams are the language of EEs so you need to post one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you know why this is caused and what I could do to remedy this
> situation?

As soon as you turn the signal generator off the rail starts to float with voltage and it could float any value. The best thing to do would be to put a pull down resistor to ground on the input, something in the tens of kilo ohm range. 50k might work. You can check to see what values floating to with an oscilloscope. If there's something else pulling up the rail like a pull-up resistor on the PCB this might not work.

Comment: Added a 47k pull-down resistor, the problem with my isolator seems to have gone away. Many thanks for your help!